# Please give step by step procedure how to set up mk-heartbeat?

Tags: monitoring

I am new to mysql as well as mattkit . I want to know how to set up mk-heartbeat in master server or slave server? which query I have to execute and where to install mattkit in the master server or slave server?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Kuku

Answer (score 1):

create a mattkitdb database on each host, then:

On the master server:

mk-heartbeat --database mattkitdb --table heartbeat_table --user mattkit --interval 30 --update --host localhost &

On the slave server:

mk-heartbeat --database mattkitdb --table heartbeat_table --user mattkit --interval 30 --monitor --host localhost --file /tmp/heartbeat &